# Why is my Android intent filter for URL host not working?

Tags: android, url-scheme

In my manifest file:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:name=".App"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="jsfiddle.net"/> 
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.phonegap.DroidGap" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"> <intent-filter> </intent-filter> </activity>
```

I tried putting the intent filter stuff for handling the URL scheme/host in the other activity, and creating a new one, and making a single intent filter, but none of them are working. The URL always just loads as normal instead of launching my app. I'm using Android 3.0 and a samsung galaxy tab. If it matters, this is a phonegap based application.
[Test](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: You might want to check my answer [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568792/oauth-and-custom-scheme-result-in-a-err-unknown-url-scheme-in-chrome/15601063#answer-15601063