# OAuth and custom scheme result in a "ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME" in Chrome

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

I've been stuck on this for hours now as the thing was working before but suddenly stopped to behave as expected. I don't really know how and why as I've been re-checking every single line of code in the process without being able to see what's wrong so I'm asking you guys for help.

Alright. So I've a `LoginScreen` activity with a button starting a new `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` on click. This start the OAUTH proccess in the browser with a `ApiManager.OAUTH_CALLBACK_URI` set to `stjapp://oauthresponse`.

Here's my `AndroidManifest.xml` part for this activity :

```xml
<activity
    android:name=".LoginScreen"
    android:label="@string/application"
    android:launchMode="singleTask">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="stjapp" android:host="oauthresponse" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

How I start the `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` in my activity :

```cs
private View.OnClickListener loginHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
             OAuthClientRequest request = null;
             try {
                request = OAuthClientRequest
                    .authorizationLocation(ApiManager.OAUTH_AUTHORIZE)
                    .setClientId(ApiManager.CLIENT_ID).setRedirectURI(ApiManager.OAUTH_CALLBACK_URI)
                    .buildQueryMessage();
            } 
            catch (OAuthSystemException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } 
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(request.getLocationUri() + "&response_type=code"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
```

And here's a screenshot of what happens in the browser :

[image]

There, I'm supposed to get back to my `LoginScreen` activity and handle the `code` query parameters within `onNewIntent` method but ... yeah, the thing doesn't work as expected anymore.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Everything work as expected opening the link with Android's built-in browser. Start to feel like I'll have to use an internal `WebView` instead of letting this part of the OAuth proccess outside. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like this is a [Chromium bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=181186). The workaround I'm using is a PHP landing page for the RedirectURI that opens the app via JavaScript (which is not affected by that bug):

```
<script language="javascript">
    window.location = 'myscheme://myhost/?<?=$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]?>';
</script>
```

Comment: I mark as accepted answer as you linked to the chromium-related issue. I'll see which alternatives fit my need. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error and resolved it by prefixing the url with `http://`.

Answer (score 2):

In Chrome version 40 and up, this bug has resurfaced, but only if you are manually entering the URL of the redirect page in the address bar.  The issue is on the chromium issue tracker [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=459156).

The response with the "workaround", pasted from the issue:

> OK, I've found out that the window.location redirect via intent will
>   work, AS LONG as it is clicked from an external source or link on
>   page.  If you manually enter the address of the redirect page into the
>   address bar, the redirection / opening of the app will fail with said
>   error.
>
> So, sending a link to the redirect page in an email or SMS will work
>   just fine when the user clicks the link.  Manually typing the address
>   into the address bar will fail.  `window.location = chromeUrl;` should
>   work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

only if you are manually entering the URL of the redirect page in the address bar. The issue is on the chromium issue tracker here.

The response with the "workaround", pasted from the issue:

OK, I've found out that the window.location redirect via intent will work, AS LONG as it is clicked from an external source or link on page. If you manually enter the address of the redirect page into the address bar, the redirection / opening of the app will fail with said error.

So, sending a link to the redirect page in an email or SMS will work just fine when the user clicks the link. Manually typing the address into the address bar will fail. window.location = chromeUrl; should work just fine.