# Open link in email for confirmation in application rather than in web site

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I created a cordova application for ios and android, where the user must create an account. He then receives an e-mail containing a link, on which he must click to validate the account. How do I get the link to open in the app rather than the device browser? I have seen information on deep-links, but is this the correct way to do that?

Comment: Have you referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30546737/11833795)?

Answer (score 0):

You should define url in manifest under activity

```
<intent-filter
                android:autoVerify="true"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

                <data
                    android:host="www.geeksempire.net"
                    android:pathPrefix="/createshortcuts.html"
                    android:scheme="https"/>
                <!-- command to TEST >>> adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https//...." net.geekstools.floatshort.PRO -->
            </intent-filter>
```

Also check this https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common

Comment: this is the idea, but is there a solution for ios, or better for cordova, including solutions for android and ios? More, is it, today, the solution to use compared to deep-linking?

Comment: check this https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/receive