# React native with Firebase FCM

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement push notification with React Native and Firebase through [this documentation](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.0.x/messaging/introduction).

I set up the settings I need by the tutorial.

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'
import { Input, Text, Button } from '../Components'
import type { RemoteMessage } from 'react-native-firebase'
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase'
import type { Notification, NotificationOpen } from 'react-native-firebase';

export default class TestComponent extends Component {

  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.SetUpAuth();
    await this.SetUpMessaging();
    this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen: NotificationOpen) => {
      // Get the action triggered by the notification being opened
      const action = notificationOpen.action;
      // Get information about the notification that was opened
      const notification: Notification = notificationOpen.notification;
    });
    const notificationOpen: NotificationOpen = await firebase.notifications().getInitialNotification();
    if (notificationOpen) {
      console.log(notificationOpen)
      // App was opened by a notification
      // Get the action triggered by the notification being opened
      const action = notificationOpen.action;
      // Get information about the notification that was opened
      const notification: Notification = notificationOpen.notification;
    }


  }
  componentWillUnmount() {

  }


  async SetUpAuth() {
    const credential = await firebase.auth().signInAnonymouslyAndRetrieveData();
    if (credential) {
      console.log('default app user ->', credential.user.toJSON());
    } else {
      console.error('no credential');
    }
  }
  async SetUpMessaging() {
    this.notification2 = new firebase.notifications.Notification()
      .setNotificationId('notificationId')
      .setTitle('My notification title')
      .setBody('My notification body')
      .android.setChannelId('test')
      .android.setClickAction('action')
      .setData({
        key1: 'value1',
        key2: 'value2',
      });

    this.notification2
      .android.setChannelId('channelId')
      .android.setSmallIcon('ic_launcher');
    console.log('assa')

    onTokenRefreshListener = firebase.messaging().onTokenRefresh(fcmToken => {
      console.log('token generated ->', fcmToken);
      //   store.dispatch(DeviceActions.SetFCMToken(fcmToken));
    });

    const fcmToken = await firebase.messaging().getToken();
    if (fcmToken) {
      // user has a device token
      console.log('has token ->', fcmToken);
      console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser._user)
      firebase.database().ref(`/users/${firebase.auth().currentUser._user.uid}`).set({ pushToken: fcmToken })
      //   store.dispatch(DeviceActions.SetFCMToken(fcmToken));
    } else {
      // user doesn't have a device token yet
      console.error('no messaging token');
    }

    const messagingEnabled = await firebase.messaging().hasPermission();
    if (messagingEnabled) {
      // user has permissions
      console.log('User has FCM permissions');
    } else {
      // user doesn't have permission
      console.log('User does not have FCM permissions');
      await this.RequestMessagePermissions();
    }

    messageListener = firebase.messaging().onMessage((message: RemoteMessage) => {
      console.log(`Recieved message - ${JSON.stringify(message)}`);
    });

    notificationDisplayedListener = firebase
      .notifications()
      .onNotificationDisplayed(notification => {
        // Process your notification as required
        // ANDROID: Remote notifications do not contain the channel ID. You will have to specify this manually if you'd like to re-display the notification.
        console.log(`Recieved notification 1`);
      });
    notificationListener = firebase
      .notifications()
      .onNotification(notification => {
        console.log(notification)
        firebase.notifications().displayNotification(this.notification2)
        // Process your notification as required
        console.log(`Recieved notification 2`);
      });
  }


  async RequestMessagePermissions() {
    console.log('request')
    console.log('Requesting FCM permission');
    await firebase
      .messaging()
      .requestPermission()
      .catch(err => console.err(err));
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>

      </View>
    )
  }
```

When I try to use it in postman I get success:

```
{
  "success": {
    "results": [
        {
            "messageId": "0:1525013439417985%a0cec506a0cec506"
        }
    ],
    "canonicalRegistrationTokenCount": 0,
    "failureCount": 0,
    "successCount": 1,
    "multicastId": 6840884736220792000
  }
}
```

But in my debugger (by console.log) I don't see any new incoming message or something else. I sent a message to my device with the token I added to this post but nothing happened.

it works only when app is in foreground, But I want to make it work also when app in background/closed the app

Comment: Are you testing on android or ios?

Comment: I tested in android. after it work in android, I will test in ios

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.0.x/notifications/introduction#Remote-Notifications) you need `onNotificationOpened` listener for `android`, when the app is in background

> **Android Background**: `onNotificationOpened` triggered if the notification is tapped.

`onNotificationDisplayed` is for *IOS app in background* and  `triggered if content_available set to true`

```
notificationBackgroundListener = firebase
    .notifications()
    .onNotificationOpened(notification => {
      // Process your notification as required
      console.log(`Recieved notification 2`);
    });
```

Comment: I added my post and added the listener but still same issue. you can see I call it on componentDidMount

Comment: It'll work only when the `notification` is tapped, also try defining and logging your listener the same way as done in `SetUpMessaging` module and `getInitialNotification` only gets called when the tapped notification opens the app.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how to make the notification, because local notification show me icon and works good and also when I'm on foreground. but in background I don't see nothing

Comment: So in foreground you see notification but in background there is no notification?

Comment: right. in foreground I see because I declared it         firebase.notifications().displayNotification(this.notification2)

Comment: Try adding [this](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.0.x/messaging/android#(Optional)-Background-Messages) to your manifest,  to display a heads up notification, for background messages. Also check if you've followed all the steps [here](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.0.x/messaging/receiving-messages#4)

Comment: Does this work with the steps mentioned in my previous comment? Any updates, otherwise i'll need to try it on a separate project.

Comment: Hey Pritish, yes I did step by step with react-native-firebase docs you sent and nothing changed. I get it only when the app is in foreground. not in background. maybe do i need to make any service-worker?

Comment: That might not be required since the docs don't say so, the rest will be taken care of by the settings in the `manifest` and the `class` files.

Comment: yes that's what I think so.. I don't have solution yet. I waste some days on it.

Answer (score 2):

If your notification is working fine when your app is in foreground then the problem is with your service. There are two possible reasons it's not working.

1. Either you are sending the payload as

   ```
   {   
        time_to_live: 86400,
        collapse_key: "xxxxxx",
        delay_while_idle: false,
        registration_ids: registration_ids,
        notification: payload
    }
   ```

   instead of

   ```
     {
          time_to_live: 86400,
           collapse_key: "xxxxxx",
           delay_while_idle: false,
           registration_ids: registration_ids,
           data: payload
     }
   ```

which is because the key in notification is recieved only when app is in foreground.

2. Another possible reason could be the service worker is getting killed for some reason. ex: I was using a one plus which auto kills the service  when I force close the app. So you can try debugging your service in native code by adding log or attaching a debugger

also make sure to add google-service.json file in your android/app folder

**Edit**:

```
{
 "registration_ids" : ["reg_id"],
 "time_to_live": 86400,
  "collapse_key": "test_type_b",
  "delay_while_idle": false,

  "notification": {},   
  "data": {
    "subText":"sub title R",
    "title":"Notification Heading R",
    "message":"Short big text that will be shown when notification is expanded R",
    "color":"red",
    "actions": ["hello", "welcome"],
    "vibrate": true,
    "vibration": 1000,
    "ticker": "My Notification Ticker",
    "imageUrl": "https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/712/1*c3cQvYJrVezv_Az0CoDcbA.jpeg" ,
    "bigText": "blalMy big text that will be shown when notification is expanded"
  }
}
```

Here is my headers

```
Authorization: key=mykey:myKey
Content-Type: application/json
```

Request:

```
 https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

which is of post and params are of raw type

Comment: What is collapse key? I added the google-service to my project. How can i know if ny service-worker killed? in react-native-firebase docs i just need to add configuration for run service-worker without actually my own code

Comment: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/blob/master/android/src/main/java/io/invertase/firebase/messaging/RNFirebaseMessagingService.java this is the service that will be receiving as per the docs you shared add a log somewhere and monitor them in android studio logs (its a method I follow there should be other better solutions too)

Comment: let me try updating the answer

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/ideaboard_tech/push-notifications/src/ib-master/android/src/main/java/com/dieam/reactnativepushnotification/modules/RNPushNotificationListenerService.java here is my forked version of react-native-push-notifications with fcm support

Comment: thank you. do you have also example working of this package work with firebase-function? I mean to send push notification with this library and firebase functions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170663/discussion-between-gaudam-thiyagarajan-and-adir-zoari).

Answer (score 0):

you can use Headless JS to run task in background and you should write some native code to handle task , unfortunately is only available in android 

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/headless-js-android.html

 
second way(i don't test it) is to use this library 
https://github.com/jamesisaac/react-native-background-task#installation

ps:firebase and other push notification service like onesignal handle push notification easily and you should not be concerned unless you want unique notification for each user

Comment: Hey, I'm not sure I need to use in more packages. I already use react-native-firebase and it should work but I don't know why.. in addition I tried in react-native-fcm but it same issue. works only in foreground. I'm happy to hear push notification easily in firebase, but I stuck with it almost whole day.

Comment: do you what to have custom notification for each user

Comment: no. I want to make regular notification with react-native-firebase.

Comment: if you can receive notification in background  but not parse their data ,you can enable deep link in firebase and it will make to automatically launch your app and in js side you can parse data

Comment: look at this example you should implement in native side and interact with data in js side  https://www.tatvic.com/blog/tangled-up-in-deeplinking-firebase-has-a-solution/

Comment: in js side setup https://medium.com/react-native-training/deep-linking-your-react-native-app-d87c39a1ad5e

Comment: i made this bug too please be aware of it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29116574/scheme-host-not-working-on-android-lollipop-click-on-link-to-open-app

Comment: sorry but not understand why I need to use deep linking to get notification in background. I want to make push notification with firebase.

Comment: i see you do some work with data from firebase, i assumed you can't take that data , if you don't need that data all things should be done in native side